# How do we set landscape orientation for all application in Android source code?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-source

I am working in Android source code. I port android os to embedded board. We need to set landscape orientation at aosp level for all applications. 
Pls, anybody have idea about that how can i tackle this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the past there was `ro.sf.hwrotation`, but Google removed this property. However, some people have resurrected it. Lineage OS is pretty trustworthy. Search their code for uses of this property in github project https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_native. Here are a couple examples:

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_native/commit/a9fa1c9c19d6ac00aa0073ef23b7a1d95f8e0a90

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_native/commit/8c36832b66e9ae793cf79820d83628d136bfd117

Comment: Why the downvote? This code works in production, perfect for embedded board development just like the asker requested.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it at your Application level and change it

Under the `AndroidManifest.xml` , you can use

```
<activity>
android:screenOrientation="landscape">
</activity>
```

And it will set your orientation default to **landscape** for the application

Comment: Not useful... Asker wants to know about AOSP modification not changes to Android apps.

Answer (score -1):

I have got the perfect solution to make the screen orientation of a device.

#### Step#1:

#### Create one Service called: "LayoutService.class"

```
package com.example.dialogtest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;

public class LayoutService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "LayoutService";
    public static final String ORIENTATION = "orientation";

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        final LayoutService mService;

        LayoutService getSystemService() {
            return LayoutService.this;
        }

        public LocalBinder() {

            super();
            mService = LayoutService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public LayoutService() {
        orientation = 0;
    }

    private static LayoutService instance = null;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    int orientation;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
            final int startId) {

        instance = this;
        orientation = intent.getIntExtra(ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d(TAG, "Orientation : " + orientation);

        final WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        final CustomLayout customlayout = new CustomLayout(orientation);
        manager.addView(new View(this), customlayout);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public static LayoutService getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private class CustomLayout extends LayoutParams {

        public CustomLayout(final int i) {

            super(0, 0, 2005, 8, -3);
            gravity = 48;
            screenOrientation = i;

        }
    }
}
```

#### Step#2:

#### Register LayoutService to your app AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".LayoutService"/>
```

#### Step#3:

#### Start your service by setting your orientation

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LayoutService.class);
        intent.putExtra(LayoutService.ORIENTATION,
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        startService(intent);
```